# Find a recurrence for the number of ways to arrange cars in a row with $n$ parking spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, induction, recurrence-relations

Find a recurrence for the number of ways to arrange cars in a row with $n$ parking spaces if we can use Cadillacs or Hummers or Fords. A Hummer requires two spaces, while a Cadillac or Ford requires just one space.

I know I need to use a recurrence relation model such as $$a_n=a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$$ but I don't know how to apply the concept to to this question fully. I have done a little bit of preliminary work but I do not know if it is necessarily correct:

We can assume that$$a_1 = 2$$Since given 1 space we can put either a Cadillac or a Ford. And we can also assume that$$a_2 = 5$$Since given 2 spaces, we can put CC, CF, FC, FF, or H. But where do I go from here?

Comment: In what direction have your own efforts towards this question been?

Comment: I legitimately do not know how to apply this concept to the question, and I can't seem to find any examples like this in my text book or anywhere else online. I realize it's unconventional here to not show any work, but I am legitimately stuck at square one. I'm not expecting a solution, but maybe a hint in the correct direction to get me started.

Comment: How about small values of $n$? What if you have 2 parking spots? Or 3? Or 4?

Comment: Okay, I did some basic preliminary work for 1 or 2 parking spots. But I still don't know how to come to a recurrence model from that.

Comment: A valid parking arrangement with $n$ cars consists of either one with $n-1$ cars with an added $C$ or $F$, or $n-2$ cars with an added $H$. So the recurrence relation is
$$a_n = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}. $$

Comment: That actually makes perfect sense. Can you please post that as an answer, @Math1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill a parking lot with $n$ spaces, you can either:

1. Fill the first $n-1$ spaces and then put a Cadillac or a Ford at the end; there are $2 \cdot a_{n-1}$ ways to do this ($a_{n–1}$ ways to fill the first $n-1$ spaces, and $2$ ways to fill the last space)
2. Fill the first $n-2$ spaces and then put a Hummer at the end; there are $a_{n-2}$ ways to do this

Adding the two, we get
$$a_n = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$$